# Arrays: find two numbers such that their sum is maximum with some additional conditions

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Given a set of numbers and a number `k`, find the maximum sum such that if you pick a number at index `i` you should not pick any number from index `i - K` to index `i + K`.

This problem was asked in google to my friend. I am not able to figure out a solution better then a naive `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in O(n) by keeping track of the maximum of all values seen in the first i-K-1 entries in the array.

Python code:

```
A=[3,9,10,3,6,7,1,5]
K=2
m=A[0]
bestsum=0
for i in xrange(K+1,len(A)):
    m=max(A[i-K-1],m) # stores maximum of values in A[0],A[1],...,A[i-K-1]
    bestsum=max(bestsum,A[i]+m)
print bestsum
```

For each index i we combine A[i] with m which is the highest value seen in the initial values of the array A[0],..,A[i-K-1].

Comment: initially m should be max (A[0] to A[k-1]) ?

Comment: it will fail for case : `9 0 12 200 1 9 7 2`  and `k= 4`

Comment: @anon It gives 18 (formed from 9+9) for that case - what do you think the right answer should be?

Comment: i think 200 if we consider that no element within range of i-k and i+k should be selected

Comment: i am specificaly talking about the case when `N < 2*k`  and you calculate for the first time `max(A[0] , A[k+1])` and don't consider  any of `A[1] to A[k-1]` .

Comment: @anon Perhaps the difference in opinion is with respect to how many numbers you are allowed to pick?  The question title says "find two numbers" so I don't think 200 is a legal solution (because it is only 1 number).  However, the question text itself leaves it ambiguous as to whether a single number is allowed.  If you are allowed to pick just 1 number then I agree that you are right.

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to modify this http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/dynamic_programming/positive_subset_sum or http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/dynamic_programming/max_subarray_sum.

Sorting the array before may not be acceptable for the question

Comment: The question asks for **2 numbers**. it is not subset-sum, you do not want subset that sums to `k`, you want maximum sum of 2 numbers with a restriction that their difference is greater then `k`.

Comment: @amit not the difference its is the index difference if , i is the index then it should not like in (i-k, i+k)

Comment: Oh, I see. Still not subset-sum though.